# Magento 2 SOAP API error

Tags: c#, php, magento, soap, magento2

I followed this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481515/how-do-i-configure-the-token-based-authentication-of-magento-2-0-soap-api-object) and created a c# project to communicate with Magento2 SOAP api. However, upon running and trying to get response it is throwing error

> "Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation
>   'catalogProductRepositoryV1Get'."

I am using the demo database comes with **magento 2.0.4**. Could someone please help to resolve this? Thanks.

### Base class:

```
public static class MagentoSOAP
    {
        private static BasicHttpBinding GetBinding()
        {
            return new BasicHttpBinding();
        }

        private static void AddAuthorizationHeader(IClientChannel clientChannel)
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty hrmp = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            hrmp.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "os1mv1gg3l64hkwxtdk7ahgldyj0xxmi");

            OperationContextScope contextScope = new OperationContextScope(clientChannel);
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = hrmp;
        }

        public static catalogProductRepositoryV1PortTypeClient Product
        {
            get
            {
                var client = new catalogProductRepositoryV1PortTypeClient();
                client.Endpoint.Binding = GetBinding();
                AddAuthorizationHeader(client.InnerChannel);
                return client;
            }
        }
    }
```

### My Main:

```
 try
            {
                var product = MagentoSOAP.Product.catalogProductRepositoryV1Get(new ProdcutRepository.CatalogProductRepositoryV1GetRequest()
                {
                    sku = "24-WG084"
                });
                int id = product.result.id;
                Console.WriteLine(id.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Hi @AshishAhujaツ please find my updated post. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. This makes the question much more clearer.